# MVC ASP.NET Single User Login Models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have created an MVC ASP.NET web application. I selected the single user login option when creating the application. I would like to use the auto-generated database, but also add attributes to the user table. I successfully added attributes, but it seems as though the models are not being updated. Normally I would go to the database edmx in the models folder and update the models from the database, but with the auto-generated code, I can't seem to find the edmx anywhere. Any information on how to update the models or how this type of operation is to be done is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using code-first entity framework?

Comment: @Glitch100 no, I don't believe so. I never physically created the database or models however. They were both generated when scaffolding out a new MVC application with single user login.

Comment: Which MVC version and EF are you using Jon? BTW if you created MVC ASP.NET web application by default it is a code-first. Until MVC 4 asp.net mvc uses Simple Membership and MVC 5 and up uses Identity to create Users